# What is the canonical basis in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology, phase-transition

In a [paper  from 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05687), Johannes Bausch et al refers to a classical state of a many-body quantum system to be a product state in the canonical basis. I was wondering what this “canonical basis” is referring to? Is it the same as what is referred to as the computational basis, as in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/what-is-meant-by-the-term-computational-basis)? i.e. two linearly independent states of a particle, such as spin up or down to represent a 1 or 0? Or is it something else?

Comment: in this context, it's the same as "computational basis", that is, some reference orthonormal set of states, as explained in the linked post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [appendix](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2017/12/18/1705042114.DCSupplemental/pnas.1705042114.sapp.pdf) of the paper, it is mentioned that the classical Hamiltonian they refer to is in the computational basis. This confirms a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672740/what-is-the-canonical-basis-in-quantum-mechanics#comment1509111_672740) posted by gLS.

Answer (score 0):

The classical state of an $N$-body system can be completely described by $6N$ variables called the [canonical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates). These variables come in three pairs for each particle/body $q_i,p_i$ with $i=1,2,3$ such that they obey the Hamilton’s canonical equations:

$$\dot q_i = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\\ \dot p_i=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i} $$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system.

So the space of all classical states lies in $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$ and your basis vectors are the ones that diagonalise your Hamiltonian.

Comment: Can the downvoter provide feedback?

Comment: given the context, I doubt this is what they meant with the term. Here "canonical basis" is probably just a synonym of "computational basis"

Comment: This answer is explicitly about classical mechanics. The question is explicitly about quantum mechanics.